# Storing a Lambda Expression in a Variable

Tags: c#

I think my brain has become fried as i'm struggling to do something simple.  In my application i have the following code to configure Nhibernate (my issue is not specific to Nhibernate).

```
return Fluently.Configure()
    .ExposeConfiguration(c => {
        c.EventListeners.PostInsertEventListeners = new IPostInsertEventListener[] { new LoggingEventListener() };
        c.EventListeners.PostUpdateEventListeners = new IPostUpdateEventListener[] { new LoggingEventListener() };
   });
```

However I need to store the configuration (the stuff inside ExposeConfiguration) inside a private variable.  I can do the following:

```
return Fluently.Configure()
    .ExposeConfiguration(c => _configuration = c);
```

Where _configuration is a private variable.  But this doesn't add my extra configuration options (the EventListeners stuff).  I've played around with various things but i guess my lambda knowledge isn't as good as i thought.

I'd appreciate your help.  Thanks

Comment: I think you should also post the declaration (delegate) of ExposeConfiguration, + what is it that you want to save in _configuration (declaration would also help).

Answer (score 94, accepted):

A lambda expression is just a delegate that often maps to one of the `Func<T1, T2, ..., TResult>` variants.

```
Func<T1, TResult> myVar = c => _configuration = c;
```

Replacing `TResult` and `T1` with the relevant types.

That might work for you.

Comment: +1, but note a lambda expression can map to any compatible delegate type. It's just often used with `Func<>`

Comment: Is it not the other way around? Func<T1,TResult> rather than Func<TResult,T1>, ... etc.?

Comment: @NeverStopLearning Yes, you're right. I got the type parameters the wrong way around. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Why am I getting a `cannot convert from 'System.Func<someViewModel, someType>' to 'System.Linq.Expressions<System.Func<someViewModel, object>>'`? Maybe it's one of the exceptions where it doesn't map - I'm trying to set a binding in Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Great answer, although I was a little confused at first how T1 and TResult correspond with the function. Here's an example that may be a bit clearer: `Func<int, string> numberToString = (num) => { return num + "";};`

Answer (score 2):

## With C# 7.0 local functions

```cs
TResult matchDuplicates (T1 c) => _configuration = c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Assuming `_configuration` is going to store what you were using in your first bit of code.  It should look something like this:

```
return Fluently.Configure().ExposeConfiguration(c => {
c.EventListeners.PostInsertEventListeners = _configuration;
c.EventListeners.PostUpdateEventListeners = _configuration;});
```

If there are any kind of cast errors from the compiler, you can always use:

```
_configuration.Cast<IPostInsertEventListeners>();
```