# Xamarin.Forms - Possible to variable-ize a SetBinding() lambda parameter?

Tags: c#, lambda, xamarin, xamarin.forms, linq-expressions

In Xamarin forms, we set a binding on a control like:

```
myLabel.SetBinding<MyViewModel>(Label.TextProperty, viewModel => viewModel.LabelText);
```

Is there a way to store the second parameter (the lambda expression) in a variable?

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4379105/422845), I've tried:

```
Func<MyViewModel, string> myLambda = viewModel => viewModel.LabelText;
myLabel.SetBinding<MyViewModel>(Label.TextProperty, myLambda);
```

But the 2nd parameter gets a red underline with the error

> cannot convert from 'System.Func<someViewModel, someType>' to
> 'System.Linq.Expressions<System.Func<someViewModel, object>>'

Comment: take a look at this: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.BindableObjectExtensions.SetBinding%7BTSource%7D/p/Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject/Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty/System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7BTSource,System.Object%7D%7D/Xamarin.Forms.BindingMode/Xamarin.Forms.IValueConverter/System.String/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. The generic `source` parameter in this case is of type `Expression<Func<MyViewModel, string>>`, not `Func<MyViewModel, string>`. Both of these types are initializer in the same way but have very different meaning. See 
[Why would you use Expression> rather than Func?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct)
 for more details.

```
Expression<Func<MyViewModel, string>> myLambda;
myLambda = viewModel => viewModel.LabelText;
myLabel.SetBinding<MyViewModel>(Label.TextProperty, myLambda);
```

Comment: Ah, an Expression, ok awesome...now apparently, for the return value of the lambda expression, it is expecting an object - `Argument 3: cannot convert from 'Systemlinq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<MyViewModel, string>>' to 'Systemlinq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<MyViewModel, object>>'`...?

Comment: Oh, I just had to change the `string` param to a generic `object`, so the following worked: `Expression<Func<MyViewModel, object>> myExpression = viewModel => viewModel.LabelText;`

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can do it with delegates.  You can refer this [tutorial by MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb397687.aspx) to learn how to do that. If the name of Viewmodel class you use for page is `MyViewModel`,  you can do something like this.

```
delegate string del(MyViewModel viewModel);
 del myDelegate = x => x * x.LabelString;
```

Then pass `myDelegate` to the binding statement as second parameter.

```
myLabel.SetBinding<MyViewModel>(Label.TextProperty, myDelegate);
```